# BigQuery charges on cross project queries

Tags: google-bigquery

I have project A, which contains all my BQ data sets. And I have project B which has the scripts and the querying logic. Project B has access to project's A data sets.

If I query project A data from project B, which of the two projects will incur the costs of the query? The project with the data or the project that does the querying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project from which you run the query will be the one who will incur the costs.

You can also see this more clearly in [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) inputs where the projectId is sent as a separate parameter to the Query

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The billing charges related to the query jobs are applied to the Billing account associated to the project that executes the query; however, the view **owner** keeps getting the charges related to the storage of the source data. Based on this, since the Project B's analysts are using the resources, these tasks will be charged to this project. You can take a look on the [BigQuery pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#how_charges_are_billed) documentation that contains the following information about this matter:

- **How charges are billed**

> Each project you create has a billing account attached to it. Any charges incurred by BigQuery jobs run in the project (such as query jobs) are billed to the attached billing account. **This is true even if project resources are shared with others outside your organization**. BigQuery storage costs are also billed to the attached billing account.

Comment: The quote from [BigQuery pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#how_charges_are_billed) is inaccurate [now]. It says *"Each project you create has a billing account attached to it. Any charges incurred by BigQuery jobs run in the project (such as query jobs) are billed to the attached billing account."* But not: *"This is true even if project resources are shared with others outside your organization."* So this needs verification. I'm currently in the process of finding it out.